# AddPOP3Account not exposed in Redemption Session.Accounts

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, office-interop, outlook-redemption

I am trying to set up an Outlook profile for use in an educational application that tests users skills in Outlook. We are using **C# and Redemption** for interaction with Outlook. With the aid of the Profman library I created the profile, then with the RDO library I added a PSTStore after logging in with the new profile. (*I need the application to run without messing with the user created profile and settings*)

However, when trying to add a POP3 account, as per the examples in the Redemption tutorials, the **AddPOP3Account method is not available**. I am obviously missing something here, but I cannot understand what.

This is the code I am using:

```
Redemption.RDOSession Session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
Session.Logon("Des", missing, false, true); 
var Store = Session.Stores.AddPSTStore(@"D:\Des.pst", _ 
rdoStoreType.olStoreUnicode, "Des Mail");
var Accounts = Session.Accounts;
var POP3Account = Session.Accounts.AddPOP3Account("Joe The User", _
                                      "address@domain.demo", _
                                      "Pop3server.domain.demo", _
                                      "SmtpServer.domain.demo", _
                                      "LogonUserName@domain.demo", _
                                      "ThePassword!")
```

The last line is the one with the error, as the AddPOP3Account method is not available for some reason.

Comment: What is the exact error? Are you sure you are using a version of Redemption that actually implements that method? AddPOP3Account was added in version 5.6.

Comment: @Dmitry Yep, this is it. It is usually that simple. We are not using 5.6... Thank you for the immediate reply!